# How to Merge multiple Select Queries in One Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Have these 4 Queries I want to select data From table like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
Month    Total Fee        Fee Deposit        Fee Due    Fine
---------------------------------------------------------------
October   200,000           100,000          100,000    5,00
```

My Queries are:
1

```
SELECT Sum(Fee)AS'TotalFee', DueDate AS'Date' 
FROM VoucherTB 
GROUP BY DueDate
```

2

```
SELECT Sum(VoucherTB.Fee)AS'FeeDeposit', DueDate AS'Date' 
FROM  VoucherTB 
WHERE FeeSubmission='Paid' 
GROUP BY VoucherTB.DueDate
```

3

```
SELECT Sum(Fee)AS'FeeDue', DueDate AS'Date' 
FROM VoucherTB 
WHERE FeeSubmission='UnPaid' 
GROUP BY DueDate
```

4

```
SELECT Sum(RevenueTB.Fine)AS'Fine', VoucherTB.DueDate AS'Date' 
FROM RevenueTB 
INNER JOIN VoucherTB 
ON venueTB.VoucherNo=VoucherTB.VoucherNo 
GROUP BY VoucherTB.DueDate
```

Comment: Please describe more, it's unclear, what is your exact problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
SELECT  
  v.DueDate AS'Date',
  Sum(CASE WHEN v.FeeSubmission = 'Paid'   THEN v.Fee ELSE 0 END) AS 'FeeDeposit', 
  Sum(CASE WHEN v.FeeSubmission = 'UnPaid' THEN v.Fee ELSE 0 END) AS 'FeeDue',
  Sum(r.Fine)AS'Fine',
  Sum(r.Fee) AS 'TotalFee'
FROM  RevenueTB AS r
INNER JOIN VoucherTB AS v ON v.VoucherNo = r.VoucherNo
GROUP BY v.DueDate
```

Comment: Thanks Query is working and give result when i used it without Fine or Inner join but when i use same query not give proper result

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from
(
SELECT Sum(Fee)AS'TotalFee', DueDate AS'Date' 
FROM VoucherTB 
GROUP BY DueDate
) A
left join
(
SELECT Sum(VoucherTB.Fee)AS'FeeDeposit', DueDate AS'Date' 
FROM  VoucherTB 
WHERE FeeSubmission='Paid' 
GROUP BY VoucherTB.DueDate
)B on B.Date = A.Date 
left join
(
SELECT Sum(Fee)AS'FeeDue', DueDate AS'Date' 
FROM VoucherTB 
WHERE FeeSubmission='UnPaid' 
GROUP BY DueDate
) C on C.Date = A.Date 
left join
(
SELECT Sum(RevenueTB.Fine)AS'Fine', VoucherTB.DueDate AS'Date' 
FROM RevenueTB 
INNER JOIN VoucherTB 
ON venueTB.VoucherNo=VoucherTB.VoucherNo 
GROUP BY VoucherTB.DueDate
) D on D.Date = A.Date
```

Comment: Glad your query is resolved. Don't forget to accept this as an answer.